# Formating generated .data file to XML

Tags: python, xml, string

I have some generated data files I want to format to XML:

```
1234=>item1:something11:

something11<COMMA>item4:something12:

12something<END_OF_OBJECT_LINE>
1238=>item8:something12:

something11:<END_OF_OBJECT_LINE>
2345=>item2:something12:

something11:<END_OF_OBJECT_LINE>
123=>item1:something1:

something11<COMMA>item2:something:

11something<COMMA>item4:something:

11something<END_OF_OBJECT_LINE>
```

What I Tried to do is to replace some specified regular expression to make it look like XML:

```
with open("OGfile.data", "r") as f:
    with open("tempfile.data", "w") as fo:
    # formating file to XML format
        contents = f.readlines()
        contents.insert(0, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n<Module>\n<Object id='")
        contents =[w.replace("<END_OF_OBJECT_LINE>\n", "'/>\n</Object>\n<Object id='") for w in contents]
        contents =[w.replace("=>", "'>\n     <Attribute name='") for w in contents]
        contents =[w.replace('<COMMA>', "'/>\n     <Attribute name='") for w in contents]
        contents =[w.replace(':something', "' value='something") for w in contents]
        # saving formated file to new file
        contents = "".join(contents)
        fo.write(contents)

# fixing invalid last line from formated file with open("tempfile.data", "r") as f2:
    with open("finalfile.data", "w") as fo2:
        contents2 = f2.readlines()
        contents2 = [w.replace("<END_OF_OBJECT_LINE>", "'/>\n</Object>\n</Module>") for w in contents2]
        contents2 = "".join(contents2)
        fo2.write(contents2)
```

and It works fine, I made it into:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Module>
<Object id='1234'>
     <Attribute name='item1' value='something11:

something11'/>
     <Attribute name='item4' value='something12:

12something'/>
</Object>
<Object id='1238'>
     <Attribute name='item8' value='something12:

something11:'/>
</Object>
<Object id='2345'>
     <Attribute name='item2' value='something12:

something11:'/>
</Object>
<Object id='123'>
     <Attribute name='item1' value='something1:

something11'/>
     <Attribute name='item2' value='something:

11something'/>
     <Attribute name='item4' value='something:

11something'/>
</Object>
</Module>
```

BUT, there is one problem, I am changing `contents =[w.replace(':something', "' value='something") for w in contents]` just by taking this value but if it would start with something different instead of "something" i would be doomed. I have been thinking about using regex to take string between `"Attribute name:"` and `"<COMMA>"` or `"<END_OF_OBJECT_LINE>"`, but my attemps failed misserably because I am quite new into programming and python. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You're having trouble because you're expecting too much from regular expressions.  Using regular expressions to extract data from a text file is fine, but trying to parse XML with them is more than they're designed to handle.  Instead, gather the data that you require from your text file, then write your XML file based on that data.  If there's an existing XML file from which you also require data, parse it using a real XML parser or XPath tech such as XPath.  Then combine the data and write out the targeted XML file.

Comment: @kjhughes the problem is that my file in general has way more lines and basically I have many files like that so I have to make it work somehow. When I will have my xml file then I will parse it and combine with another I already have generated in xml format, I know it sounds like a lot of uneccesary work but I have to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see the connection between your comment and the guidance I provided.

Comment: As @kjhughes pointed out, it would be much better to build the xml in the right way rather than as a string. Take a look at `dicttoxml` module.

Comment: @LMC I undestand but in that case I would have to convert my .data file to dictionary but it is for me problematic because I don't know how to separate "Attribute name" and "Atrribute value" in correct way. The only thing I tought was to use regex. Sorry If I am asking dumb questions, I printed my first "Hello world" 3 weeks ago.

Comment: Data seems to have "vertical" records starting with `[number]=>` . Are `<COMMA>` and `<END_OF_OBJECT_LINE>` literally written in the file?

Comment: @LMC yes, it is literally written in the file. The only things I changed are id, name and value, but the whole structure of file is the same

Answer (score 0):

Parsing data with regular expressions and then building an XML using `lxml`.
Caveat: the regex expects up to 2 `<COMMA>` instances per "record" which produces up to 3 Attribute elements.

```
import re
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element("Module")

with open("/home/lmc/tmp/test.txt", "r") as f:
    df = f.read() 
    result = re.finditer(r'(?s)\n?(\d{1,5})=>(?:([^:]+):(.+?))(?:(<COMMA>)([^:]+):(.+?))?(?:(<COMMA>)([^:]+):(.+?))?(<END_OF_OBJECT_LINE>\n)', df)
    for m in result:
        obj = etree.SubElement(root, "Object")
        obj.set("id", m.groups()[0])
        at = etree.SubElement(obj, "Attribute")
        at.set("name",m.groups()[1])
        at.set("value",m.groups()[2])
        for idx in range(len(m.groups())):
            if m.groups()[idx] == '<COMMA>':
                at = etree.SubElement(obj, "Attribute")
                at.set("name",m.groups()[idx + 1])
                at.set("value",m.groups()[idx + 2])

print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True).decode("utf-8"))
```

Result:

```
<Module>
  <Object id="1234">
    <Attribute name="item1" value="something11:&#10;&#10;something11"/>
    <Attribute name="item4" value="something12:&#10;&#10;12something"/>
  </Object>
  <Object id="1238">
    <Attribute name="item8" value="something12:&#10;&#10;something11:"/>
  </Object>
  <Object id="2345">
    <Attribute name="item2" value="something12:&#10;&#10;something11:"/>
  </Object>
  <Object id="123">
    <Attribute name="item1" value="something1:&#10;&#10;something11"/>
    <Attribute name="item22" value="something:&#10;&#10;11something"/>
    <Attribute name="item44" value="something:&#10;&#10;11something"/>
  </Object>
</Module>
```